# Как посчитать количество используемых уникальных слов

Tags: google-spreadsheet

**Условие:**
Каждая строка, это текст которым может содержать в себе несколько предложений (отзывы покупателей)

**Требуется:**
Получить на выходе список, частоты использования уникальных слов, например:

1. Привет - 73 раза
2. Как - 50 раз
3. Дела - 23 раза

Можно отделить функциями слова друг от друга по признаку пробела, тем самым получить много ячеек с разными словами, которые повторяются.

Как дальше отделить уникальные? Вот где начинаются проблемы. Так как для подсчета необходимо указать конкретное слово, а оно может у меня повторяться неограниченное кол-во раз.

Буду признателен, если поможете советом в какую сторону двигаться.

Comment: Без примера данных не будет мультиков.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Частоту вхождений можно посчитать в [QUERY](https://contributor.pw/tags/query/) как количество приведенных (`lower`) слов.

Положим, что есть линейный массив выражений `A:A`, слова которых разделены пробелом, тогда будет справедлива формула

```
=QUERY(
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(A:A;;99^99);" "));
  "select lower(Col1), count(Col1)
    group by lower(Col1)
      order by count(Col1) desc
        label lower(Col1)'WORD', count(Col1)'COUNT'";
  1
)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Пример в Таблице](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/180VaurMpPn-KadlB7qnXulo39qeX9E6aenZvPcCQGUQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Это то что нужно! Не совсем понял, зачем нужен параметр 99^99?

Comment: В этой [статье](https://contributor.pw/post/google-sheets-join-everithing-with-formula/) написано, почему используется QUERY для объединения данных. Только вместо `99^99` там подсчитывается общее количество строк.